# Get database from /var/lib/mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winscp, winscp-net

I am trying to get a database from a Linux box and am doing it using WinSCP .NET assembly with the following code:

```
SessionOptions sessionSettings = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Scp,
    HostName = "******",
    UserName = "*****",
    Password = "*****",
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "****************************"
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
   session.Open(sessionSettings);

    TransferOperationResult ibData = session.GetFiles("/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1", @"Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1\Database\ibdata1.myd");
    ibData.Check();
    TransferOperationResult ib_logfile0 = session.GetFiles("/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0", @"Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Project1\Project1\Database\ib_logfile0");
    ib_logfile0.Check();
    TransferOperationResult ib_logfile1 = session.GetFiles("/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1", @"Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1\Database\ib_logfile1");
    ib_logfile1.Check();
    TransferOperationResult mysql = session.GetFiles("/var/lib/mysql/mysql", @"Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Project1\Project1\Database\mysql");
    mysql.Check();
    TransferOperationResult oreka = session.GetFiles("/var/lib/mysql/oreka", @"Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1\Database\oreka");
    oreka.Check();
    TransferOperationResult test = session.GetFiles("/var/lib/mysql/test", @"Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project1\Project1\Database\test");
    test.Check();
}
```

Now that I have the database from `/var/lib/mysql`, I don't know how I am suppose to extract the data I need to continue. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hardly clear.

But I suppose you want to dump a database to a file using the [`mysqldump` command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html) and then download the dump.

You can use the [`Session.ExecuteCommand` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_executecommand) to call the `mysqldump`. But you obviously need a shell access to the server to do do that.

Comment: That didn't work. I'm new to grabbing a db from a Linux box, so is there something I'm missing when trying to grab it?

Comment: *"That didn't work"* - If you want keep being that vague, please do not waste our time and go away.

Comment: I gave you once chance, you have wasted it.

Comment: Your followup question: [WinSCP Issue Grabbing MySQL Database](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39598774/850848), where you somehow forgot to give credit.